# Classic ASP LocaleID

Tags: asp-classic

I have an old classic asp app that I want to install on IIS 7.5
I use LocaleID 2057 because a think it has the most appropriate settings for me (dates, number, etc). The problem is that I want to change the default "digit grouping symbol" from comma to this character: ` (the key under the ESC).

I have changed the LocaleID directly on IIS, under ASP settings.

Do you know from where does IIS takes this default values for each LocaleID? Or if those settings can be changed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think 2057 is a codepage, so you can set it at the top of your page:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="2057"%>
```

Comment: yes, I know but the problem is how can I change the default settings for 2057?

Comment: Ah, ok. So when you say "changed the LocaleID directly on IIS, from ASP settings" do you mean you have altered the settings of the locale? Wouldnt you do this through international and regional settings in control panel?

Comment: If I change the settings in control panel nothings happens in IIS.

Comment: Did you restart IIS afterwards? I would probably even restart the machine if it still won't take effect!